Combine Dropdown Control(Choice Column) & add a New Choice Value in the same form
Is there a way to Combine Dropdown Control(Choice Column) and add a New Choice Value in this specific Choice column in the same form without using a PA Flow with http request to Sharepoint?
enter image description here
Power Automate - Update Choice Field values - YouTube
Would be grateful for any tips or help.
Greetings
enter image description here

refer to this when asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
